# Infinite descending subsequence of closed intervals of $[0, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory

The question i'm asking arises from lemma $12$ of Laver's proof for the consistency of Borel's conjecture. It has some set theoretic assumptions but i doubt they are needed in the proof. And since i'm not really good with analysis i would be really glad if someone could point me in the right direction.

---

Let $I_n$, $n \lt \omega$, be closed intervals in $[0, 1]$ such that for all $n$, there exists some $0 \le m \le n-1$ such that $I_n = [m/n, (m+1)/n]$. Then there exists an infinite descending subsequence of the above intervals.

---

My semi-idea: Let $I_n = [a_n , b_n]$. Then the $a_n$'s have either an increasing infinite subsequence or a decreasing infinite subsequence. WLOG assume the $a_n$'s themselves are increasing. Since $[0, 1]$ is bounded, the $a_n$'s converge to a real $u$. By the same argument we may assume the $b_n$'s are decreasing and converge to the same real $u$ because the length of $I_n$'s is decreasing. Now here i wanted to somehow consider an $\epsilon \gt 0$ and find intervals included in eachother but i'm failing to go further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If, as you claim, you can (by passing to a subsequence) get the $a_n$'s to increase and the $b_n$'s to decrease, then your intervals are nested. If $m<n$ then $a_m\leq a_n<b_n\leq b_m$, and so $I_n\subseteq I_m$. I think the real problem is your "WLOG". What if, for example, the $a_n$'s are decreasing?

Comment: Are you sure that "descending sequence of intervals" is intended to mean that the intervals are nested? If so, isn't the sequence with $I_n=[\frac1n,\frac2n]$ a counterexample?

Comment: This does seem like a counter-example, maybe the set theoretic assumptions are needed after all. Because the same argument that there is a descending subsequence is used in every text i've seen on borel's conjecture without any proof.

Comment: Althouth to be fair Laver actually doesn't say nested but he says a subsequence of the intervals which converges to a single real $u$. But in Freidman's notes he explicitly says descending.

Comment: Getting the subsequence to converge to a single real is much easier. By passing to a subsequence, arrange that the $a_n$'s converge to some real $u$. Then observe that the $b_n$'s also converge to the same $u$, because the distance between $a_n$ and $b_n$ converges to $0$. (The distance was $1/n$ for the original sequence; it'll be the same or smaller for the subsequence.)

Comment: You can apply the set-theoretic theorem $(\omega)\to (\omega)^2_2 $ which can be proved in ZF+Dependent Choice. I dk  if this is a theorem of ZF but I doubt it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Now that i have thought more about this, it seems that the convergence of the subsequence is enough for this lemma and requiring it to be descending is too steong. But the fact that Jech (In multiple forcing) and Freidman(In his notes) say that it can be descending confuse me. But thats a question for another time. Thanks.

Comment: @DanielWainleet: But this combinatorial principle is not enough i think(is it? I'm not 100% sure). Because the each time the possibilities for the $I_n$'s gets multiplied by $n$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet The partition relation $\omega\to(\omega)^2_2$ is provable in ZF, either by a direct argument (the homogeneous set can be arithmetically defined from the partition) or by observing that it's $\Pi^1_2$ and therefore absolute between the universe and Gödel's $L$. (Actually, Shoenfield absoluteness is overkill here.) But I don't (yet) see the relevance of this partition relation to the problem at hand.